# How to use COUNT() in subquery

Tags: sql-server, count, subquery

My query gets you the Customers that have a Sales Header or have a Sale Invoice between the dates '2014-06-01' AND '2014-12-31'.

Now I want to create a two new columns that shows how many Sale invoices between the dates '2014-06-01' AND '2014-12-31' and Sales header each customer got.

The problem here is that I don't really understand how to think, i get this error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Here is my SQL Query.

```
SELECT t1.Name, /*THIS PART GIVES ME THE ERROR*/ (SELECT COUNT(t5.[Bill-to Customer No_]) as he
                FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Sales Header] t5
                WHERE EXISTS
                            (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Customer] t6 
                                WHERE t5.[Bill-to Customer No_]=t6.[No_])
                GROUP BY t5.[Bill-to Name]
                ) as TempSa


FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Customer] t1
WHERE (EXISTS
         (SELECT *
          FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Sales Header] t2
          WHERE t2.[Bill-to Customer No_] =t1.[No_])
       OR EXISTS
         (SELECT *
          FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Sales Invoice Header] t3
          WHERE t3.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-12-31' AND t3.[Bill-to Customer No_] = t1.No_))
```

---

This two querys give me the right amount of Sales header per customer and Invoices between the dates per customer. How to merge this two querys into the select statement in the query above?

```
    SELECT t1.[Bill-to Name], COUNT(t1.[Bill-to Customer No_]) as Temp
FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Sales Header] t1
WHERE EXISTS
            (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Customer] t2 
                WHERE t1.[Bill-to Customer No_]=t2.[No_] )
GROUP BY t1.[Bill-to Name]
```

.

```
SELECT t1.[Bill-to Name], COUNT(t1.[Bill-to Customer No_]) as Temp
FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Sales Invoice Header] t1
WHERE EXISTS
            (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Customer] t2 
                WHERE t1.[Bill-to Customer No_]=t2.[No_] AND t1.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-12-31' AND t2.[No_]='101716' )
GROUP BY t1.[Bill-to Name]
```

Comment: Your query is using SQL Server syntax conventions so I changed the tag from mysql to sql-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `GROUP BY` in the subquery.  I'm not sure if you just need to remove it or replace it with a correlation clause, but this will fix the syntax error:

```
SELECT t1.Name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(t5.[Bill-to Customer No_]) as he
        FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Sales Header] t5
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Customer] t6 
                      WHERE t5.[Bill-to Customer No_] = t6.[No_]
                     ) 
      ) as TempSa
```

However, I think the value you want is:

```
SELECT t1.Name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(t5.[Bill-to Customer No_]) as he
        FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Sales Header] t5
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [dbo].[MNO International AB$Customer] t6 
                      WHERE t5.[Bill-to Customer No_] = t6.[No_]
                     ) AND
              t5.[Bill-to Name] = t1.Name
--------------^ correlation clause instead of `GROUP BY`
      ) as TempSa
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it would work somehow but didn't know how to make it work :)